# How to migrate a standalone Redis instance to a Kubernetes Master/Slave replication

Tags: migration, kubernetes, redis, redis-sentinel

I'm migrating an application from a single server to a Kubernetes cluster.

I'm no really sure what's the best option to migrate the Redis service, therefore I'd like to get the advice of anyone :)

I have deployed [the Spotahome redis operator](https://github.com/spotahome/redis-operator) and create a `RedisFailover`.

The Master/Slave Redis is working fine, but is empty, so I need to figure out what's the most secured way to import the data without any loss.

### What I tried

I found [the REPLICAOF command](https://redis.io/commands/replicaof) which is exactly what I need, but the issue that Sentinel reverts the config after a moment.

I'm afraid that this happen while syncing the data and therefore have a partial import.

### Another idea

Backup/restore in Redis is nothing else than copying the `dump.rdb` file so I was thinking to shutdown the pods in Kubernetes, shutdown the old Redis instance, copy the `dump.rdb` file in the pod's volumes, and starting again the pod.

### So now

- Do you see any other way to achieve what I'm trying to do?
- Is copying the `dump.rdb` file the best option?

Comment: The options you mentioned seem quite reasonable. Personally I would go for `dump.rdb`. You can be pretty sure about consistency of this solution.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, that what I did.